# Passing data from AuthorizeCore to HandleUnauthorizedRequest then Action in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

I have a custom implementation of `AuthorizeAttribute` that *handle unauthorized user access* were I override the following methods: `AuthorizeCore`, then `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`.

- The logic for checking user access is in `AuthorizeCore.`
- The redirect to controller/action is in `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`.

Now, I would like to know **how can I send data from AuthorizeCore to controller/action?** Following that sequence:

1. `AuthorizeCore` create a message.
2. `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` do the redirect and pass the previously created message.
3. The controller/action receive the message.

**Note:** I don't want to receive the message via QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this. You may try to add:

```
filterContext.Controller.TempData["auth_fail_message"] = "Error message";
```

in HandleUnauthorizedRequest method. Then you may access temp data from error action. 
You may use asp.net session object as well.

Comment: Remember that I cannot access the `filterContext` from `AuthorizeCore`. I only have the `httpContext`.

Comment: You may create field in AutorizeAttribute class called message. Set it in AuthorizeCore method and then use this variable in HandleUnauthorizedRequest to set it in temp data. I assume it should work. Otherwise you may use HttpContext.Current.Session to store message there.

Comment: Good comment. As far as I have reviewed few posts it may depend on MVC version. In this case you may use session to transfer message between these message or actions. One more thing: you have some logic in your AuthorizeCore method which validates if user should be authorized. You may reuse it in HandleUnauthorizedRequest method to get the message you need. In this case you won't have to pass any data between these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
public string Messages { get; set; } // declare "Messages"
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
     Messages = "bla bla";// Or set in controller
     ....
     ....
     ....
     ....
     base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext); 
}


protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
   Messages.ToString(); // Read Message ="bla bla"
   base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

2.Method Set message using controller;

```
[CustomAuthorize(Messages = "Bla Bla Bla")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```